# В каком времени употребить слово?

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология

"Он учился в школе, находящейся в центре города" или "находившейся в центре города"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оба варианта возможны. Если школа и ныне там, то логично "находящейся". Если её там уже нет - находившейся.

Впрочем, это стилистика. Строгого смыслового разграничения между этими случаями нет.